# How to control Windows Media Player remotely using Java?

Tags: java, activex, wmp, jacob

this is the first time I´m posting something here.

I´m working on a Project where I want to control the Windows Media Player through different Input Modalities (like Multitouch, a 3D Mouse...). At the moment I´m trying to find a way to control the Windows Media Player remotely.

Write now I´m stuck on controlling the Player  through a Java Program using the Jacob Library. It seems to be connecting to the WMP, but it does not execute my controls (Play in this case).

Does anybody have any experience with controlling the WMP remotely? My preferred language would be Java, do you know about an alternative/better way than using Jacob for the COM Bridge? Or do you know about a different approach, with which it would be easier to control the WMP? 
I have to keep in mind, that i will need to be able to read out the input from the different devices and make the device work with the control of the WMP.

I hope somebody can help me! 
thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to control WMP through Java?

Comment: because one of the input device is going to be a gesture recognition tool, which will come with a java wrapper. If you have any better suggestions, i would be grateful to hear them! I already tried visual c#, didn´t make it work... And than i would need a connection between the c# and java for the input devices... If you got any suggestions for easier solutions, i would love to hear them!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to take a look at the [Windows Media Player SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and in order to controll it remotely you may have to implement a [small client server application](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/216.html) which does the remote control job for you.